# how to parse huge xml file in json object using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
d3.xml("treeData.xml", function(error, treeData1) {

//xml str            
    var xmlstr = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(treeData1);

    // Create x2js instance with default config
    var x2js = new X2JS();

    var obj=x2js.xml_str2json(xmlstr);
    //alert(obj['root'][0]);
    var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(x2js.xml_str2json(xmlstr));    
    //alert(jsonObj);

    treeData=obj;
    root=treeData['root'];
    //root =obj['root'];
    update(root);
});
```

i'm using this code for parsing but its not working for xml file larger than 300mb.